# Equivalence of definitions of the Axiom of Continuity in Economics

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, economics

Statement $1$: If $(a_n, b_n)_{n \geq 1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in $X \times X$ satisfying $a_n \succsim b_n$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n, b_n) = (a,b)$, then $a \succsim b$.

Statement $2$: If $x_n \to x$ and $x_n \succsim y \ \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $x \succsim y$ and if $x_n \precsim y \ \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $x \precsim y$.

Definition: $\succsim$ is a binary relation on $X \times X$ such that it is complete ($x \succ y, y \succ x, x \sim y$ are the only possibilities) and transitive. We denote $x$ is more preferable to $y$ by $x \succsim y$. Here, $\succ$ is strict, $\succsim$ is weak and $\sim$ denotes indifference (that is, $x$ is as preferable as $y$ to the consumer).

Statement $1$ is essentially the definition of the Axiom of Continuity in Economics. $X$ is supposed to be the choice set, an infinite subset of the Euclidean space. I am trying to verify if the second statement means the same as the other one.

$1 \implies 2:$ Consider the sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $x$ such that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $x_n \succsim y$. In $(1)$, define $b_{n \geq 1} := y$ and we have the desired result. Similarly, do it the other way and we have the second part of $(2)$ proved.

However, the problem lies in proving $2 \implies 1$. I have been trying this for quite sometime and I haven't made any progress yet. I did not find much help on the Economics Stack site either.

Comment: What does $\succsim$ mean?

Comment: @WillM. Well it's the preference relation. It's a binary relation on $X \times X$ such that it is complete ($x \succ y, x \prec y, x \sim y$ are the only possibilities) and transitive.

Comment: I took economic courses back in the day, long ago, but if you want answers, you have to provide contexts and definitions of your notations. You may be lucky and get away with it but I think this is probably an easy exercise.

Comment: @WillM. Figured out this is false. We can create an example using one lower semi-continuous line and an upper semi-continuous line such that each point in the upper line is above each point in the lower line and there's a jump discontinuity between the two. We can extend this idea to more than one dimension (or simply fix all other coordinates as constants).

Comment: @dictatemetokcus: you may find your answer [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/45606/36322) You asked this question there and it seems that the answer gives all you need. You may be missing some assumptions in the OP in MSE concerning the relation between the topology of $X$ and the preference relation on $X$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz If you look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4187960/how-does-the-logical-implication-work-here) there's a counter example to the same problem.

Comment: @dictatemetokcus: are you saying that (1) iff (4) is false in the link to Eco MS?

Comment: @OliverDiaz (1) is not exactly same as my Def. 1. My Def. 1 is same as (5). The question originally asked was 5 iff (7) ∧ (8). The proof consists of a lot of irrelevant statements so I don't really know. [The Def. 1 and (N) for N=1,5,7,8 are from the Eco SE page you linked.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two statements are indeed equivalent to each other, and either one can be used as the definition of a continuous preference on the set $X$.

Assume that Statement 2 is true, then ${\rm UC}(y)=\{x : x \succsim y\}$ and ${\rm LC}(y)=\{x : x \precsim y\}$ are closed sets for each $y$. Since the preference $\succsim$ is complete, ${\rm SUC}(y) = \{x : x \succ y\}$ and ${\rm SLC}(y) = \{x : x\prec y\}$ are open sets for each $y$.

Assume that Statement 1 is not true. Then there is a sequence $(a_n,b_n)\in X\times X$ such that $a_n\succsim b_n$ for each $n$, $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$ as $n\to\infty$, but $a\prec b$.

The first step is to choose some particular $n$ such that $b\succ a_n \succsim b_n \succ a$. Choose a neighborhood $U$ of $a$ with $U\subset {\rm SLC}(b)$, and choose a neighborhood $V$ of $b$ with $V\subset {\rm SUC}(a)$. Since $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$, we must have $a_n \in U$ and $b_n \in V$ for $n$ large enough. Pick one such $n$, then
$$b\succ a_n \succsim b_n \succ a$$
Keep $n$ fixed, and choose a smaller neighborhood $U_0$ of $a$ with $U_0\subset {\rm SLC}(b_n)$, and a smaller neighborhood $V_0$ of $b$ with $V_0 \subset {\rm SUC}(a_n)$. Again, if $m$ is large enough, $a_m \in U_0$ and $b_m \in V_0$. Pick one such $m$, then $a_m\prec b_n$ and $b_m\succ a_n$. But together this yields
$$b_m\succ a_n \succsim b_n \succ a_m$$
which contradicts the requirement $a_m \succsim b_m$. Hence, if Statement 2 is true, then Statement 1 must also be true.